# How to access animation parameters in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Simple Question,

I created an animation of the a sprite and I added a Bool to say that he can Attack. When this bool is true it allows him to attack, and move into the attack state.  Can someone please give me the code to access that BOOL paramater that I have declared in Unity in C# please.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve boolean Animator parameters by using the [Animator.GetBool()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.GetBool.html) method.

```
Animator animator;

void Start() {
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void Update() { 
    var attacking = animator.GetBool("Attacking");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DemoControlScript : MonoBehaviour {


//First, we will create a reference called myAnimator so we can talk to the Animator component on the game object.
//The Animator is what listens to our instructions and tells the mesh which animation to use.
private Animator myAnimator;

// The start method is called when the script is initalized, before other stuff in the scripts start happening.
void Start () {
    //We have a reference called myAnimator but we need to fill that reference with an Animator component.
    //We can do that by 'getting' the animator that is on the same game object this script is appleid to.
    myAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();

}

// Update is called once per frame so this is a great place to listen for input from the player to see if they have
//interacted with the game since the LAST frame (such as a button press or mouse click).
void Update () {

    //Set the VSpeed and HSpeed floats for our animator to control walking and strafing animations.
    myAnimator.SetFloat ("VSpeed", Input.GetAxis ("Vertical"));
    myAnimator.SetFloat ("HSpeed", Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal"));




//Set Jump Boolean to true to trigger jump animation, then wait a small time and set to false so we don't jump agani.



    if(Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump")){
        myAnimator.SetBool ("Jumping", true);
        Invoke ("StopJumping", 0.1f);

    }
    if(Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump")){
        myAnimator.SetBool ("runing", false);
    }
    if(Input.GetButtonUp ("Jump")){
        myAnimator.SetBool ("runing", false);
    }
    if(Input.GetKeyUp("w")){
        myAnimator.SetBool ("runing", false);
        Invoke ("Stopruning", 0.1f);
    }
    if(Input.GetKey("w")){
        myAnimator.SetBool ("runing", true);
        Invoke ("Stopruning", 0.1f);
    }
    if(Input.GetKeyUp("s")){
        myAnimator.SetBool ("runing", false);
        Invoke ("Stopruning", 0.1f);
    }
    if(Input.GetKey("s")){
        myAnimator.SetBool ("runing", true);
        Invoke ("Stopruning", 0.1f);
    }
    if(Input.GetKeyUp("r")){
        myAnimator.SetBool ("fire", false);
        Invoke ("Stopruning", 0.1f);
    }
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, and isn't well-written code.